# Should we not pluck leaves of Tulsi after sundown?

Tags: belief, tulasi

My aunt refused to pluck a leaf from the Tulsi plant after sundown and when I asked her for a reason, she gave an answer with which I was not satisfied at all. So can anybody tell me if we should not pluck leaves of Tulsi plant after sundown or if there is no rule as such.

Comment: Ideally,, one must not touch any plant after sundown.

Comment: Related : [Why can Tulsi leaves only be picked on certain days?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3186/3122)

Comment: Pls.See this answer its said that we should not pluck the Tulsi btw. twilights. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31627/5620

Answer (score 6):

Your aunt did the right thing.

Plucking Tulasi leaves after sunset and at certain other times is strictly prohibited as per our scriptures &  is considered to be a big offence. The Devi Bhagawatha Purana (in Book 9; 24th Chapter) states that:

> Whoever holds in his neck the garland made up of Tulasî wood, gets
>   certainly the fruit of horse sacrifices at every step. He who does not
>   keep his word, holding the Tulasî leaf in his hand, goes to the
>   Kâlasûtra Hell as long as the Sun and Moon last. He who gives false
>   evidence in the presence of the Tulasî leaf, goes to the Kumbhîpâka
>   Hell for the life-periods of fourteen Indras. He who drinks or gets a
>   bit of the Tulasî leaf water at the time of death, certainlygoes to
>   Vaikuntha, ascending on a car made up of jewels. **Those who pluck or
>   cull the Tulasî leaves in the Full Moon night, on the twelfth lunar
>   day, on the passing of the sun from one sign to another, the mid-day,
>   or on the twilights, on the night, while applying oil on their bodies,
>   on the impurity periods, and while putting on night dresses, verily
>   eat off the Nârâyana’s head.**

**Edit**-Adding one more source.This one is from the book called ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=24):

> Tulasi Mahima: As regards Tulasi, it is stated that during the
>   Vaidhruti and Vyatipata times, Sunday-Tuesday-Fridays, Purnima and
>   Amavasyas, Sankranti days, Dwadashi Tithis and during Ashuchi days,
>   plucking Tulasi is as atrocious as cutting one’s own head. **Plucking**
>   Durva on Sundays, **Tulasi on Raatris and Sandhyas**, Dhatri Patra in
>   Kartika Month, **no person desirous of achieving Punya would never
>   attempt.**

Answer (score 4):

In Sri Vaishnava practices, even on permitted days, the Tulasi is plucked only in the morning and never in the afternoon.

In the Srivaishnava Sadachara Nirnaya by Sri Narayana Yatindra Mahadesikan, a Smriti verse is quoted:

> āravāre ca śukre ca manvādiṣu yugādiṣu
>
> nāharet tulasīpatram madhyāhnātparatastathā

nāharet = do not pluck

madhyāhnātparatastathā = in the remaining portion of the day after noon.

The author doesn't quote the name of the Smriti but the verse appears to be from the Bhrigu Samhita (35.533) http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/4_rellit/vaisn/bhrgus_u.htm

Answer (score -2):

Yes it's of course a mythological saying that we shouldn't pluck tulsi leaves after sundown. As we go in deep ,we can see that all the mythological issues have a scientific background.
After sundown there will be disease causing mosquitoes and some other insects flying.

Comment: You should include which mythology or purana mention not to pluck tulsi after sundown with appropriate citation. Also note that scientific speculation is not allowed here. Visit [answer].