# Watering tulsi plant on sunday is not allowed?

Tags: tulasi

My family says not to water the tulsi plant on sunday and even not to pluck it on that day.
Is it right??
Please explain it with proper justification.

Comment: Probably not allowed. Plucking at least isn't allowed on sundays and many other days. Check my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11228/4732

Comment: Personally speaking even my mom does not water our tulasi plants on sundays.