# Sources describing rituals for collecting herbs

Tags: mantras, tantra, ayurveda

I have found the following ritual for collecting herbs in the Kamaratna-tantra, which is a Hindu tantra from the 14th century (although its contents may be derived from older source).

Are there more sources describing rituals/mantras for collecting herbs?

> To collect medicinal plants a man should fast over night, and in the following morning, after offering salutations to Mahadeva, should approach the plant with due respect and utter the mantra (No. 1)—
>
> > “Ye betāl, pishāsa, rākshas, and creeping animals that live in the plant, go away at the command of Shiva.”
>
> Then the plant should be saluted by uttering the mantra (No. 2)—
>
> > ‘Oh mother, thou hast they birth in the nectar, and thou incresest strength and vitality. Let me drive away the sins and diseases.’
>
> After this the plant should be dug with a flawless weapon while uttering the mantra (No. 3)—
>
> > ‘I dig thee with the same sacred hand with which Brahmā, Bhrigu, Indra and Varuna dug you.’
>
> After this prayer, mantra (No. 4) should be recited—
>
> > ‘Oh mother, what is my fault? May the divine life depart from this plant, so that I may be saced from the sin of uprooting and cutting it. Go thou to heaven doing good to me.’
>
> After this prayer, the medicinal plant should be dug on a Sunday in Paushyā lunar mansion and in the Rabi Yoga while uttering the eight-lettered mantra (No. 5). The plant should then be cut after reciting the six-lettered mantra. (No. 6)
>
> [source](https://archive.org/stream/KamaratnaTantra#page/n19/mode/2up)

Comment: A very excellent Question.

Comment: There is mantra, specific days and rules for plucking tulasi leaves to offer to Vishnu.

Comment: @ram please post an answer, specifying the source books for this mantra, if you posses knowledge of these. I am very curious to know.

Comment: see previous similar [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/why-can-tulsi-leaves-only-be-picked-on-certain-days), and [answer](http://www.lotusimprints.com/new/blog/2008/12/14/qa-worship-of-tulasi-devi-on-dvadasi-17-other-questions/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, for collecting leaves like Durva, Bilva and Tulasi to be used in Puja there are certainly some mantras that are used.

### Tulasi chayana mantra:

> Om TulasyamritanAmAsi Sada Twam Keshava PriyA | KesavArthe Chinomi
>   TwAm Barada Bhva Shovane || Twadnga Sambhavaih Patraih PujaYAmi YathA
>   Harim | TathA Kuru PavitrAngi Kalau MalavinAshini ||

This mantra basically praises Tulasi as being born of amrita or nectar. It also asks for permission for plucking its leaves which are to be used during puja of Keshava or Lord Vishnu.

### Bilva chayana mantra:

> Om Punya Vriksha MahAbhAga MalurSreephala Prabho | MaheshpujanArthAya
>   TwatpatrAni Chinomyaham ||

This mantra also asks permission from the Bilwa tree to pluck its leaves for using them in Mahesha puja or puja of Lord Shiva.

### DurvA chayana mantra:

> Om Sahsra ParamA Devi SatamulA SatankurA | Sarvam Haratu Me PApam
>   durvA Duswapna NAsini ||

This is to be chanted while collecting Durva grass (which is of course very dear to Lord Ganesha and also it represents Rahu samidh among the navagrahas). The mantra praises Durva as having 100 roots and 100 seedlings and also as being capable of  removing all kinds of sins as well as the bad dreams.

Source of the mantras is a bengali book i possess called **Brihat Visuddha Nitya Karma Paddhati.**