# Is it written in our Shastras about abstinence from some acts on certain days

Tags: scripture, practice, dharma-shastras

I understand that most of the practices that are followed in the society have some or the other reasons.
Like it is very popular belief in Hindu tradition not to purchase Oil and Salt on Saturdays, not get a haircut on Thursdays and Saturdays etc.

Is there any reference in our texts that support this? Like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/why-can-tulsi-leaves-only-be-picked-on-certain-days) question provides a decent explanation of not plucking Tulsi (Basil) on specific days.

No intention to offend anyone, but just want to segregate knowledge from ignorance.